# Django HayStack Get Parameter from URL and update default query accordingly

Tags: python, django, solr, django-urls, django-haystack

I have implemented the search functionality using haystack + solar in django, now what the scene is I have another page, that will use the same functionality but one differences.

`1st module - http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/`

the module displays all registered users then search is functional on this module,

`2nd module - http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/46000/`

now what this will done, it will first filter all users who from city code 46000 then search will functional on it.

Now i wanted to know how can i do with using same module or inherit module 1 or any other idea to minimize code?

what i want is that on module 1, can i check if there is an `url parameter` then update the default query else not? how to do this ?

what i have do is

```
def __call__(self, request, city_code = None):
        if city_code == None:
            print 'taqi'
        else:
            print city_code
```

for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/` it print taqi on the console and for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/46000/`

the values of `city_code` it get this in `saerch_view` method of `search_view_factory` class, but now where to pass this value to `change default query set`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use one of the Haystack generic views - http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html#new-django-class-based-views

The code would be something like:

```
from haystack.generic_views import SearchView

class MySearchView(SearchView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(MySearchView, self).get_queryset()
        city_code = self.kwargs.get('city_code')
        if city_code:
            return queryset.filter(city_code=city_code)
        return queryset


# urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/users/$', MySearchView.as_view()),
    url(r'^/users/(?P<city_code>\d+)/$', MySearchView.as_view())
)
```